# How do I make the range in a gauge item start and end at the same position?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, gauge

I need the green ring to start and end in the same position.

[image]

Starting position should be 0 and then the ending position will be an expression.

When I run it, I get this:

[image]

how can I change the range to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: I suspect imgur will be blocked on many work networks, you may want to use SO hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the answer was to go to the Radial Scale Properties, under "Layout" tab and change the "Sweep angle" to 360.